# parameter must be a descendant of this view android appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator

I am trying to remove a view from parent view. when i do    App.globalWindow.remove($.wrapper);

the app crashes- the xml file looks like

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="wrapper">
        <View id="overlay" />
        <View id="content" layout="vertical">
            <ScrollView id="sv_list" height="80%" layout="vertical" top="10" />
            <Button id="btn_select" top="10">Select</Button>
        </View>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see based on current info is that you are calling remove method in some other .js file & you are expecting **$.wrapper** to be the ID of that view you want to remove, but **$.wrapper** will only be available in same .js file to which that XML belongs.

Still, you can resolve this issue by a nice-catch here.

Since, remove method on any **Ti.UI.View** or **Ti.UI.Window** actually removes a child view from this view's hierarchy, so you can do it in reverse-way, means, getting the parent of wrapper view and call remove method on that.

Just like this:

```
// it will always work if you intend to use remove method
var wrapperParent = $.wrapper.getParent();
wrapperParent.remove($.wrapper);
wrapperParent = null;

// OR

$.wrapper.getParent().remove($.wrapper);
```

Don't get surprised if you don't see **getParent()** method anywhere in Appc Docs :)

**Suggestions:**

- Always try to avoid using global variables for heavy objects like Window, Views, etc.
- Never use Ti.App.addEventListener(), instead use callbacks, or Backbone event dispatchers **[Read Here](http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/10/the-case-against-ti-app-fireevent-2/)**.
- There are always reference back to parent views & child views, hence you can make use of them.
- If you need some heavy-duty methods to be called upon child-views, then you can use **exports** method in child-views and call that method on parent.